# aura:attribute not working for Event object

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I have this simple lightning component:

```
<aura:component controller="myEventController">
    <aura:attribute name="newEvent" type="Event"
        default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Event',
        'Subject': ''}"/>
     <form>
           <fieldset>
                <ui:inputText aura:id="evtSubj" label="Subject"
                        class="form-control"
                        value="{!v.newEvent.Subject}" required="true" />
                    <ui:button label="Submit" press="{!c.debugEventMethod}"/>
                </fieldset>
       </form>
</aura:component>
```

and its controller:

```
({
    debugEventMethod: function(component, event, helper) {
            var evt= component.get("v.newEvent");
            alert(JSON.stringify(evt));
    }
})
```

The values are not getting set when sobject is Event. If i try with any other object (Say Opportunity and Name field), that works.
Am I doing anything wrong here or is it a limitation or bug in lightning component?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I have also had trouble with setting the default value of attributes to be an object. I feel that this is likely a bug since it works for some attribute types but not others. One workaround that you could consider is to set the value with the controller on component initialization.

```
<aura:component controller="LightningController">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:attribute name="newEvent" type="Event" />
     <form>
           <fieldset>
                <ui:inputText aura:id="evtSubj" label="Subject"
                        class="form-control"
                        value="{!v.newEvent.Subject}" required="true" />
                    <ui:button label="Submit" press="{!c.debugEventMethod}"/>
                </fieldset>
       </form>
</aura:component>


({
    debugEventMethod: function(component, event, helper) {
            var evt= component.get("v.newEvent");
            alert(JSON.stringify(evt));
    },
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var evtInitialValue = { 'sobjectType': 'Event', 'Subject': ''};
        component.set("v.newEvent", evtInitialValue);
    }
})
```

---

By the way, if you look at the type of the event, you will see that when you set the default value, you are getting a string instead of an object, and that is what is preventing you from setting property values.

```
debugEventMethod: function(component, event, helper) {
        var evt= component.get("v.newEvent");
        alert(typeof evt);
}
```

Comment: Hi Martin, its not the default value I am much concerned about, but rather the fact that any field of this particular object is not getting set in the form. So any value I enter in the UI, is not getting set in the Event object attribute . The workaround I had to do is create a new attribute corresponding to each field and then pass them to Apex class and set Event object field values to those.

Comment: @Mahesh The problems are related. For some reason, when setting the default value for some attribute types as an object, the component leaves it as a string rather than converting it to an object.