# How to use <force:inputField> and <force:outputField> inside an <aura:iteration>

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, inputfield, iteration

[Here @Peter describes](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/64580/lightning-how-to-use-forceinputfield/96645#96645) a very cool way to use a `<force:inputField ... />` together with

```xml
<aura:attribute name="YourObjectType" type="YourObjectType" 
    default="{ sobjectType: 'YourObjectType' }" 
/>
```

where `YourObjectType` could be `Account` for instance.

**My js-controller is**

```javascript
({
        init : function(component, event, helper) {
            console.log('init');
            var action = component.get("c.getData");        
            action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                console.log(response.getReturnValue());
                component.set("v.opportunities", response.getReturnValue().opportunities);
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(action);
        }, 
})
```

**And my apex controller is**

```
public class elfClientOpportunityList { 
    public class data {
        @AuraEnabled public List<Opportunity>       opportunities               { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled public String                  text2                       = 'text2';
        public data() {
            this.opportunities = new List<Opportunity>();           
        }
    }
    @AuraEnabled public static data     getData() {
        data result = new data();
        result.opportunities = (List<Opportunity>) Database.query( xs.soql(
            ' SELECT *, Account.Name FROM Opportunity '
        ));
        return result; 
    }
}
```

(Sidenotes: text2 is just a placeholder for now and SELECT * does what it does in SQL using [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/49711/howto-wildcard-select-to-query-all-fields-of-objects-in-apex))

Now I need to use these fields inside an iteration over something like this

```xml
<aura:attribute name="opportunities" type="Opportunity[]" />
// ...
<aura:iteration var="item" items="{!v.opportunities}">
    // ...
    <force:inputField value="{!item.YourCustomFieldName__c}"/>
    // ...
<aura:iteration>
```

What do I need to define at the `sobjectType`-property in the `default` attribute?

I've tried this already

```xml
<aura:attribute name="opportunities"    type="Opportunity[]" default="{ sobjectType: 'Opportunity[]' }" />
```

But as an unfortunate it bring only an not helpful error message

> Aura.loadComponent(): Failed to initialize application.
> An internal server error has occurred
> Error ID: 319439292-6868 (-1241857102)

[image]

Using `List<Opportunity>` does not work either

```xml
<aura:attribute name="opportunities"    type="Opportunity[]" default="{ sobjectType: 'List<Opportunity>' }" />
```

You can't save it, because the API says:

> markup://c:elfClientOpportunityList:5,90: ParseError at
> [row,col]:[6,90] Message: The value of attribute "default" associated
> with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.:
> Source

Now I'm out of ideas and need help. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you'd need to have a more granular component as the item inside of `<aura:iteration>`.

Create a smaller granular component that contains the markup for your list item:

**c:opptyListItem Components**

```
<aura:component> 
  ...blah blah blah...
  <aura:attribute name="opptyItem" type="Opportunity" default="{ sobjectType: 'Opportunity' }"/>

  <div>
    <force:inputField value="{!v.opptyItem.YourCustomFieldName__c}"/>
    ...more fields here...
  </div>
</aura:component>
```

So in the top level component, you would have your list attribute and `aura:iteration`.

```
<aura:attribute name="opptys" type="Opportunity[]"/>

<aura:iteration var="oppty" items="{!v.opptys}>
  <c:opptyListItem opptyItem="{!oppty}" />
</aura:iteration>
```

This may seem like overkill, but everything about Lightning Components points to smaller granular components as opposed to big monolithic UIs (the prior Visualforce way).

Comment: Thanks, this would technically work... But still: overkill it is. Not everything is reusable or is intended to be reused. Sometimes a more monolithic design is a big advantage, speedup and clearly decouples things properly. So to be forced to design fine-grained *always* feels very wrong to me. It should be choice, at least for reasons like simple iterations. I will end up with bizillions of hard-to-maintain compos this way... not cool

Comment: Or hopefully Salesforce will provide a few fine-grained "list-row" components in the future. The trick here would be ideally to make a single list row component that can become *any* sObject record that you could then pass in the fields to render. To have one of these for every single sObject type would quickly become unmaintainable.

Comment: I would not expect to get something new... What is already there is fine. Only this single line should work as expected `default="{ sobjectType: 'Opportunity[]' }"` - I think this would make sense, doesn't it? Or even better: let the force:inputField be smart enough to "know" what it is, like in Visualforce apex:inputField knew... Plus we already told the framework explicitly what type it is here `type="Opportunity[]"`. As far as I understood, all that `default`-acrobatic is only a necessary workaround, because the feature isn't finished, yet - right?

Comment: As I understand it, yes.

Comment: @Peter That code does not work .Have you tried ?I tried myself in new Napili template and does not work actually.

Comment: I think the whole force:outputText implementation is extremely confusing. It doesn't make any sense to me to have some kind of metadata definition in the default value of the attribute. It feels like a very hackish way of getting information about the object that's stored in the attribute. It's also not immediately obvious how this component could be instantiated dynamically or even if it can be instantiated dynamically. At the very least I would think this component needs much better handling in the documentation.

Comment: I've also tried a more fine-grain approach to test which hasn't worked - Replacing the content of a single TD with a custom component containing only the force:outputfield tag and the passed in SObject record via attribute. I'm not sure that there's any consistently workable solution for force:inputfield or force:outputfield

Comment: @Peter after one year pause I'm retrying my luck with Lightning Components again. So far, I found most of the issues I touched last year still present... Reading through the comments and answers here, there was no viable workaround for this particular problem here and people even failed with you suggestion. Do you have any new insides? Is it's worth to spending again some hours to try? Would prefer not to dig into some known limitations. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I try it,this can not  work.

Answer (score 2):

It's about 2 years after I initially touched this issue and today I've found this **Known Issue** here  https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008gDzQAI

It confirms my ancient observations from 2015 and confirms also that the Peters fine-grained approach does not work.

For me the recommended workaround is not usefull, since ui:whatever can't out of the box deal with picklists values, field dependencies, translation and localization like number- and date-formats. It can be done, but needs an unjustified amout of complexity and code. My workaround is to use visualforce with it's mature apex:inputField instead.

Here is the Known Issue

> `<force:inputField>` is not rendering fields on UI when being used
>   inside `<aura:iteration>` tag or inside nested components in Lightning
>   application
>
> **Summary**
>
> `<force:inputField>` is not rendering fields on UI as expected
>   when being used inside `<aura:iteration>` or inside inner component in
>   Lightning application
>
> **Repro**
>
> 1. Login to your org
> 2. Try creating a sample lightning application
> 3. Create a component with below sample code snippet & try to preview the app
> 4. You will notice the fields doesn't render on the UI as expected.

```
<aura:component>  
    <aura:iteration aura:id="iteration" items="{!v.expenses}" var="expenses">  
        <force:inputField value="{!expenses.Amount__c}"/>  
    </aura:iteration>  
</aura:component>
```

> **Workaround**
>
> Try using `<ui:inputText>` or  or
>   `<ui:inputCheckbox>` instead of  for rendering input
>   fields inside `<aura:iteration>` or inside inner components

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`<lightning:inputField>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_inputField.htm) instead of `<force:inputField>`. It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the problem is with setting the default value of the attribute. With some attribute types, the default value is interpreted as a string rather than an object, [event is an example](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/89194/auraattribute-not-working-for-event-object/89230#89230). As for Opportunity[], when running the following, the `opplist2` attribute when set with `default` is logged as a string, while the `opplist3` is logged as an object (array) when set on initialization with a js Array literal.

app

```
<aura:application >
    <aura:attribute type="Opportunity[]" name="opplist1" default="{ sobjectType: 'YourObjectType' }" />
    <aura:attribute type="Opportunity[]" name="opplist2" default='[{"sobjectType":"Opportunity"},{"sobjectType":"Opportunity"}]' />
    <aura:attribute type="Opportunity[]" name="opplist3" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="c.doInit" />
</aura:application>
```

js

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper){
        console.log(component.get("v.opplist1"));
        console.log(component.get("v.opplist2"));
        console.log(typeof component.get("v.opplist2"));
        component.set("v.opplist3",[{"sobjectType":"Opportunity"},{"sobjectType":"Opportunity"}]);
        console.log(component.get("v.opplist3"));
        console.log(typeof component.get("v.opplist3"));
    }
})
```

Comment: I don't understand how to make things work this way. Will it work with force:input inside of the aura:iteration this way (v.opplist3) or not? At the .set() you are setting only the type, not the value - as far as I see. How to set type and value? Wait, I'll add my js controller, than it's easier to discuss...

Comment: Now I've added my controllers (js+apex). How to combine your technique `component.set("v.opportunities",[{"sobjectType":"Opportunity"},{"sobjectType":"Opportunity"}]);` and the "common value setting" I use `component.set("v.opportunities", response.getReturnValue().opportunities);`? Done subsequently? Won't it clash and only the last statement win?

Comment: Martin, could you tell me if this way is intended to work somehow? I still can't figure it out. Inspecting the result values `response.getReturnValue().opportunities`, even in my original code each element already has a property `"sobjectType":"Opportunity"` and it doesn't work. So how setting this manually can could it work?

Comment: Martin, at this time I think your answer does not provide an viable method to solve the issue. Possibly it's more about the reasons behind, but still I can't really understand it. Any further clarification is very welcome!

Comment: @UweHeim I agree. I was looking at this some more this evening, and it looks like my post addresses a different symptom of the underlying issue and doesn't actually solve your problem.

Comment: I see, thanks for your clarification Martin. I hope Salesforce tells us something useful soon. I have this logged also at premier+ support, but no response yet. At this time I think there is a lot of incomplete functionality and documentation.